# How to use Case statement in SQL correctly

Tags: sql, case

The below Select statement does NOT return a record for me:

Select 1:

```
    SELECT 
        Case When rcdr.PolicyNumber like '' + bmpd.PaymentReferenceNumber + '%'  
        Then 'Adc' else 'Exceed' end as System
     FROM RcDetailRecords rcdr
       join Bil_ManualPaymentDetails bmpd
       on rcdr.PolicyNumber like '' + bmpd.PaymentReferenceNumber + '%' + ''
```

Output:

```
    System =
```

The below Select statement DOES return a record for me:

Select 2:

```
     SELECT 
        Case When rcdr.PolicyNumber like '1234567890%'
        Then 'Adc' else 'Exceed' end as System
     FROM RcDetailRecords rcdr
       join BilManualPaymentDetails bmpd
       on rcdr.PolicyNumber like '1234567890%'
```

Output:

```
    System = Adc
```

Am I missing a tick '' mark somewhere in the first Select ?

**BilManualPaymentDetails Table:**

```
PaymentReferenceNumber 
123456789020161013025120
```

**RcDetailRecords Table:**

```
PolicyNumber
1234567890
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1234567890` is not like `123456789020161013025120%`, but `123456789020161013025120` is like `1234567890%`

So it appears you have the fields switched, try:

```
  SELECT 
        CASE WHEN bmpd.PaymentReferenceNumber LIKE '' + rcdr.PolicyNumber + '%'  
             THEN 'Adc' 
             ELSE 'Exceed' 
        END as System
     FROM RcDetailRecords rcdr
     JOIN Bil_ManualPaymentDetails bmpd
       ON bmpd.PaymentReferenceNumber like '' + rcdr.PolicyNumber + '%' + ''
```

Comment: awesome, thank you. takes a fresh set of eyes sometimes. Thanks again!

Comment: My pleasure, also, you don't actually need the empty string concatenated on the front.